# after sd_card save, jpeg saves distorted

Tags: android, parameters, camera, sd-card, fileoutputstream

so, I save my picture to the sd card using fileOutputStream- i have the image formatted for jpeg- but the image saves distorted.  this is weird because the thumbnail image is the correct representation of the image, but when opened, it's a series of horizontal lines.

here are some snippets from my code:

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,int height) {
    if(previewing){
        camera.stopPreview();
        previewing=false;
    }
    if(camera!=null){
        try{
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
            parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.startPreview();              
            previewing=true;
        } catch(IOException e){}
    }

}
```

and

```
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        OutputStream outputStream;


        try{
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis())); //to sd card
            imageFileOS.write(data);
            imageFileOS.flush();
            imageFileOS.close();


        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
};
```

the images (of the horizontally distorted jpeg and the put-together thumbnail) aren't uploading to the server at the moment - hoping someone has an idea of what is going on. if not i can try to upload the pics later.

Comment: when i try this on my OG droid- 2.2.3 the picture saves perfectly.  when i use my droid incredible 2 - 2.3.4 the picture saves distorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved:

in 2.2 i wasn't having an issue

in 2.3, the image was saving distorted- this was fixed with a method i called "getBestPictureSize" which is basically identical to the method i used to get the best preview size for the screen aspect ratio

this is the method for getting best picture size for the device the app is running on...

```
private Camera.Size getBestPicturSize(int width, int height)
{
        Camera.Size result=null;    
        Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
        for (Camera.Size size : p.getSupportedPictureSizes()) {
            if (size.width<=width && size.height<=height) {
                if (result==null) {
                    result=size;
                } else {
                    int resultArea=result.width*result.height;
                    int newArea=size.width*size.height;

                    if (newArea>resultArea) {
                        result=size;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return result;

}
```

this is the surfaceChanged callback, in which the above method is utilized to properly size the picture resulting from camera.takePicture( ... );

```
private Camera.Size getBestPicturSize(int width, int height)
{
        Camera.Size result=null;    
        Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
        for (Camera.Size size : p.getSupportedPictureSizes()) {
            if (size.width<=width && size.height<=height) {
                if (result==null) {
                    result=size;
                } else {
                    int resultArea=result.width*result.height;
                    int newArea=size.width*size.height;

                    if (newArea>resultArea) {
                        result=size;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return result;

}
```

you can also use this picture sizing method to get preview size, by switching out the line:

```
for (Camera.Size size : p.getSupportedPictureSizes()) {
```

for

```
for (Camera.Size size : p.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
```

hope this helps someone, as i spent a like 10 hours stressing over this function wouldn't work on my 2.3.4 but would on my 2.2

that being said- running the getBestPictureSize on 2.2 causes a force close. haven't figured out how i'm going to handle that yet

Comment: i would have liked to manipulate the method to handle in any api environment, but i added an if statement that uses "android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT" to set the picture size for 2.3+ and to do nothing for 2.2-